# 24bit RGB image, but doesn't have blue channel. How can I access it?

Tags: c#, image-processing, rgb

I need to extract a color image from a file. I have it in a byte array and I did extract it, but it has 2-channels and I have no idea how to access or get the third channel. I saw the original image, and it should be a color image. The image is 1024x720. 3 bytes per pixel.

I tried with a [1024, 720, 3] array, but it was bigger than the file, so there is no way the three channels stored like this.

```cs
                byte[] image_array = File.ReadAllBytes(ofd.FileName);
                int start = image_array.Length - (1024 * 720 * 2);
                int o = start;

                Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(1024, 720);
                BitmapData bmd = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, 1024,
                    720), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

                unsafe
                {
                    byte* scan0 = (byte*)bmd.Scan0.ToPointer();
                    for (int i = 0; i < 720; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < 1024; j++)
                        {
                            byte* tmp = scan0 + i * bmd.Stride + j * 3;

                            tmp[0] = image_array[o++];
                            tmp[1] = image_array[o++];
                            tmp[2] = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
                bmp.UnlockBits(bmd);
                pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
```

I loop through that part of the file, where the image is stored, and the result is a visible image, quite greenish, because the blue channel is set to 0, because I don't know how to get that.

Comment: Maybe it really is 16bit with RRRBBBGG bits?

Comment: Is the image encoded in any way? That might make it smaller than you expect due to compression.

Comment: I haven't got quality knowledge in image-processing, so I don't understand what this means. Maybe you are right, but I don't really know what I should do or change in my code :/

Comment: The default format of new Bitmap() is Format32bppArgb. ... So you should use 4 bytes for each pixel ... or set the format to the right one :=-)

Comment: You need to know the format of the file if you read it as an array of bytes. If you open it by using the Bitmap class it will do the decoding into color bytes for you (if it is a format that is known to the Bitmap class) Also: if you don't realy understand this, you might want to read up on how images are stored in files and in memory.

Comment: Thank you for the comments guys! I'll check out these things :)

Comment: Yeah, that looks like there's a large chance of it being 16 bit colour. Which means bit shifting to get the correct colours out.